# How to continuously sample data based on clicks in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an observable with interesting data that changes over time (`BehaviorSubject`):

```javascript
const obs = ...
```

Then I have a click action (`Subject` which gets called `.next()` upon button press):

```javascript
const clickAction = ...
```

I wish to do this:

```javascript
obs.pipe(sample(clickAction)).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

The problem I have is this: when I click my button multiple times in a row, it only logs the message once to the console. If `obs` changes, then clicking again will once again log to the console.

Expected behavior: the data (whether it has changed or not) should also be logged every time I click the button.

I thought `sample` was supposed to do this, but I reckon there must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `combineLatest` on `obs` and `sample(clickAction)`? Also, it will be helpful to have some code that way we will workout on a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sample`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/sample) isn't working in your case because:

> `sample` looks at the source Observable and emits whichever value it
>   has most recently emitted since the previous sampling, **unless the
>   source has not emitted anything since the previous sampling**.

---

#### withLatestFrom

Use [`withLatestFrom`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom) to combine click events with the latest emitted value from your source observable.

```
clickAction.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(obs),
  map(([notifier, source]) => source)
).subscribe(console.log)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-uxizci

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing this:

```typescript
export function upon<T>(notifier: Observable<any>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => {
    const latest = withLatestFrom(source)(notifier)
    const mapper = map(([, source]: [any, T]) => source)
    return mapper(latest)
  }
}
```

Which can be used like so: `obs.pipe(upon(clickAction))`